# Connect to microsoft Outlook.com through IMAP using XOauth2 in java

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, imap

Microsoft posted [a new blog entry](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2013/09/12/outlook-com-now-with-imap.aspx) about its new IMAP functionality for fetching emails using OAuth2. However, I have few to no experience with IMAP and I am having problems using the OAuth access token in IMAP.
I used to use javamail for android and, using email and password, I was able to access emails with no problem. However, I have no idea how to connect through javamail using access token, I am not even sure it is possible.
Any ideas on how to access "imap-mail.outlook.com" using IMAP and OAuth2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was letting go of javamail and replacing it with apache commons net library. The methods presented below does the authentication with outlook imap server. Apache commons lib is not as user-friendly as javamail, but it seems like it is the way to go

```
private boolean sendBase64Credentials(IMAPSClient client) {
    String base64Encoded;

    try {
        // Outlook.com specification
        // user={user@domain.com}^Aauth=Bearer {access token}^A^A
        byte[] binLogin = ("user=" + user + "\u0001auth=Bearer "
                + oauthToken + "\u0001\u0001").getBytes("utf-8");
        base64Encoded = Base64.encodeBase64StringUnChunked(binLogin);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        int code = client.sendData(base64Encoded);
        switch (code) {
        case IMAPReply.OK:
            return true;
        case IMAPReply.BAD:
        case IMAPReply.CONT:
        case IMAPReply.NO:
        default:
            System.out.println("return = ?");
        }
        System.out.println(client.getReplyString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean authenticateXoauth2(IMAPSClient client) {
    try {
        int code = client.sendCommand("AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2");
        switch (code) {
        case IMAPReply.CONT:
            return sendBase64Credentials(client);
        case IMAPReply.OK:
        case IMAPReply.BAD:
        case IMAPReply.NO:
        default:
            System.out.println("ERRO");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```